# Ternary operator in java - not understandin from compiler and jvm perspective

Tags: java, jvm, compiler-construction

Do i understand correctly this

byte b =40;

Compiler-type checking whether value belong to within range of datatype(byte) Ok, then JVM allocates memory and keep the value?

If i unerstand correct, my drama is here in ternary operator

byte a = 10<20?30:40;

Compiler knows datatype and value constant, so compiler will do comparison and assigned the value to variable “a”?? So jvm dont allocate memory in this case?

Second example

int a =30,b=20;

byte c=(a<b)?10:20;

Compiler does not know values a, b only does type checking datatypes(int)-first line,

second line compiler knows values 10 and 20 but comparison will be done by JVM(jvm knows values?)so jvm comes and do a comparison and promote the number 10 and 20 to int type??, so thhis number cannot be assigned to byte variable?… i dont know where i understand correct why number 20(false) cannot be assigned to byte…

Thank you

Explain the problem of compiler type checking and jvm in runtime

Comment: The JVM doesn't allocate memory whenever you do a computation using a primitive type.  Primitive values are held in registers and on the stack, and in fields of some object.  There is nothing special about a ternary operator in this respect.  Assuming that you are using primitive types (as in your examples), no memory is allocated.

Comment: "Explain the problem of compiler type checking and jvm in runtime" - This question is too broad.

Comment: `byte c=(a<b)?10:20;` is not valid because `a` and `b` are not *constant expressions*.  (If you declared `a` and `b` as `final`, that example should compile.)   See [JLS 15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29) and [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).   Note that this is nothing to do with type checking.  It is just a specific rule that allows an implicit *narrowing conversion* because the compiler "knows" that the value being assigned is within the required range.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am beginner in Java and I dont know whether understand correctly byte c = (a<b)?10:20; what values compiler knows(10 and 20)? and JVM knows a and b? Who wants assigned the value to byte c?

Comment: If you are a beginner at Java, you should not be asking questions about how memory is managed, and how type checking works.  They are beyond your ability to understand the answers.  Wait until you know more about how to write Java programs before you ask deep questions about how it works.

Comment: For that example, all you need to know is that you can use a type-cast to make it work; i.e. `byte c = (byte) ((a < b) ? 10 : 20);`   (If you really want to understand "why" you need to be able to read the JLS.  And you don't have enough technical knowledge for that ... yet.  And indeed, most Java programmers don't ever get that far.)

Comment: To give you a literal answer to your question: the compiler knows that `10` and `20` are `int` values and it knows that `a` and `b` are `int` variables (not `final`).

Comment: If the code doesn't compile the JVM can't execute it at all, so the question of whether the JVM allocates memory doesn't arise. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: aha, so compiler knows datatypes of literal values and knows datatypes of a and b values? and JVM only allocates memory for that datatypes in memory and keep values here? Sorry for inconvenience I am interested in it.

Comment: You should not conflate compiler and JVM’s memory management. The JVM is entirely irrelevant. The compiler follows strict rules. You can only assign an `int` value to a `byte` variable if the value is a compile-time constant and within the byte value range. In all other cases, it’s not allowed, regardless of how obvious the correctness would look to a human reader. E.g. when you have `void foo(byte b) {}`, you can not do `foo(10);` because it’s not covered by the mentioned rule.

Answer (score -1):

> *'... Compiler-type checking whether value belong to within range of datatype(byte) Ok, then JVM allocates memory and keep the value? ...'*

The value *40* is an *int literal*, so the compiler is going to evaluate if the declared *data-type* can contain it.

In other-words, the following will not compile.

```java
byte b =1234;
```

> *'... Compiler knows datatype and value constant, so compiler will do comparison and assigned the value to variable “a”?? So jvm dont allocate memory in this case? ...'*

It will only allocate the memory for a *byte*, if your provided value can fit within the bounds.

Meaning, the following will compile.

```java
byte a = 10<20?30:1234;
```

> *'... Compiler does not know values a, b only does type checking datatypes(int)-first line ...
>
>
>
> ... i dont know where i understand correct why number 20(false) cannot be assigned to byte ...'*

The interpreter is not going to traverse too deep.
I imagine if you're providing a dynamic value, it's not going to evaluate anything.

Alternately, you can declare *a* and *b* as *final*, although I'm not sure how practical that is.

```java
final int a =30,b=20;

byte c= (a<b)?10:20;
```

Comment: *"The interpreter is not going to traverse too deep.
I imagine if you're providing a dynamic value, it's not going to evaluate anything."* - Actually, this is all specified in the JLS.  It is not a question of whether the compiler (or interpreter) *could* implement it.  (Either could ... but they not allowed to ...)

Comment: To allocate memory can mean different things, depending on what you are looking at. Further, it’s not clear whether the OP referred to local variables or fields. Memory for fields in only allocated when an instance is created. Memory for local variables, on the other hand, is allocated when the thread is started, which is why you may end up with an error if the stack turns out to be too small for what your code does (unless the JVM supports stack expansion, unlike HotSpot). Further, for local variables the compiled code for, e.g. `int i = 40;`, `byte b = 40;`, or `char c = '(';` is identical.